# Angularjs fails with passing data from ASP.Net Razor view

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor

Recently I had a situation, when the user typed in input textbox something like "{{ text :}}" and saved it. And this caused the Angular fail on some pages.

So, if I pass data to my controller from Razor view like this

```
@{
   var test = "{{ test :}}";
}

<html>
<head> </head>
<body ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="test = '@test';">
</body>
</html>
```

I get following error
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=:&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=6&p3=test%20:&p4=:

Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [test :] starting at [:].

This kind of passing data is the most popular answer for questions "How to pass data from MVC Model to Angular controller". Are there any workarounds? Only AJAX call for data without Razor? Or validate user input for Angular curly braces?

Comment: Razor is parsed on the server side, angular on client side. What this will produce is `ng-init="test = '{{ test "}}';"` which does not seem valid to me. But what the error actually says is that you have an invalid character in your string: `{{ test : }}`, you cannot have an `:` in your string

Comment: I can't restrict user to type ":" in input text. I can validate for "{{" and "}}" in input text, but i don't think that's a good solution

Comment: Are you saying that the user is injecting the double curly brackets ``{{ }}`. If so, why are you allowing that?